# Shortcut version getting some object values into array in certain order?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have object with many keys, I want to get some of corresponding values into array, in certain order.

To get these values I can use deconstruction like

```
const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 2, other: 666, keys: "here" };
const { foo, bar, baz } = obj;
const array = [ foo, bar, baz ]; // 1, 3, 2
```

Of course, I can use many ways to achieve my goal, like without deconstruction:

```
const array = [ obj.foo, obj.bar, obj.baz ]; // 1, 3, 2
```

Or having these keys as an array and mapping over it.

```
const array = ["foo", "bar", "baz"].map( v => obj[v] )
```

But is there some simpler way?

In Perl, for example, is simple shortcut:

```
my %obj = (foo => 1, baz => 3, bar => 2); 
my @arr = @obj{ ('foo','bar','baz') }; # 1, 3, 2
```

And instead `('foo','bar','baz')` here I can actually use any statement which returns list of these keys as selector for object (hash).

I can't figure out something similar in JS.

Comment: You've summed up the simplest forms, though you could abstract to a method

Comment: `@obj{ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' }` would suffice in Perl. No need for those parens. One could also use `@obj{qw( foo bar baz )}`

Comment: @ikegami I added parents to indicate possibility to use any list returning statement there, because I don't seek for hardcoded string solution in JS too.

Comment: @w.k, Parens But parens have nothing to do with lists!? You'd also use `@obj{ f() }` and not `@obj{ ( f() ) }`

Answer (score 1):

Write your own util function like this or better:

For lazy folk :

```js
const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 2, other: 666, keys: "here" };
const obj2arr = (obj, fields) => fields.match(/\S+/g).map(field => obj[field]);

const arr = obj2arr(obj, 'foo bar baz');
console.log(...arr);
```

For who likes typing quotes and commas:

```js
const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 2, other: 666, keys: "here" };
const obj2arr = (obj, ...fields) => fields.map(field => obj[field]);

const arr = obj2arr(obj, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz');
console.log(...arr);
```

```
Cycles: 1000000 / Chrome/117
-------------------------------------------------------
rest arguments    25/min  1.0x   29   25   29   33   32
regex            132/min  5.3x  135  132  147  142  146
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark
```

```html
<script benchmark="1000000">
const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 2, other: 666, keys: "here" };

// @benchmark regex
const regex = /\S+/g;
const obj2arr = (obj, fields) => fields.match(regex).map(field => obj[field]);
// @run
obj2arr(obj, 'foo bar baz');

// @benchmark rest arguments

const obj2arr2 = (obj, ...fields) => fields.map(field => obj[field]);
// @run
obj2arr2(obj, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz');

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: why take a single string? just rest params? `(obj, ...fields) =>`

Comment: @pilchard i'm lazy, adding the rest variant)

Answer (score 0):

There is the `with` statement but it is deprecated

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

```js
const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 2, other: 666, keys: "here" }
with(obj) {
  const arr = [foo, bar, baz]
  console.log(arr)
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, but this syntax is pretty confusing... It is weird that `with` in SQL is also confusing , for me ;)

Comment: `var` is also kinda deprecated and promotes bugs

Comment: I see `var` here as a placeholder for declaration.

Comment: This should really be a comment and not an answer. Using `with` is not viable in any modern environment, not supported in strict mode, or node.

Comment: I bet the next comment will be: "Semicolons!!!!"

Comment: let arr;
const obj = { arr: 'test', foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 2, other: 666, keys: "here" }
with(obj) {
  arr = [foo, bar, baz]
  console.log(arr)
  console.log(obj);
} - you will have obj mutated